# Hibernate: returning a DTO that is not an Entity?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, dto, hibernate-native-query

I have the following `ContactDTO` java POJO that is a trimmed down version of my `Contact` entity that contains over 100 fields/columns

**ContactDTO:**

```
public class ContactDTO {

    @JsonProperty
    private Integer contactId;

    @JsonProperty
    private String userName;

    @JsonProperty
    private String firstName;
    
    //getters and setters...
    
}
```

I am trying to return this in a `hibernate` query as follows, note that this query works as expected when I run it manually in `MYSQL` Workbench:

```
@Override
public ContactDTO getContactDTObyId(String client, Integer id) throws ATSException {

    EntityManager entityManager = null;
    try {

        entityManager = entityManagement.createEntityManager(client);

        String queryString = "select contact_id as contactId, username as userName, first_name as firstName from " + client + ".contact where "+" contact_id = " + id + "";

        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString, ContactDTO.class);

        return (ContactDTO) query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("An error is thrown in getContactDTObyId");
    } finally {
        entityManagement.closeEntityManager(client, entityManager);
    }
}
```

The above is giving me the following error at the `getSingleResult()` line:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ContactDTO
```

How can I return this DTO object using Hibernate?

I am aware that this is not an Entity in the way that my `Contact` Entity maps to the `Contact` database table, but I thought I could still return it using `Hibernate` by populating the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a `class` as the result of a native query only works with entity classes. To specify an DTO (and unmanaged class in the spec), you need to specify a constructor on your DTO and declare a `SqlResultMapping`

Assuming you declare a three argument constructor on `ContactDTO` you should add:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "contactDTOResult",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = ContactDTO.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "contactId"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "userName"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "firstName")})
    })
```

And in your native query use the result set mapping name `contactDTOResult`:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString, "contactDTOResult");
```